# If statement and value of an input variable - Pine Script - Tradingview

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

I'm having issue with using the value of a variable used as input value, in a if statement Here's a piece of my code :

```
//@version=3
study(title="v5.0", shorttitle="v5.0", overlay=true)
PP_display = input(1, minval=0, maxval=1)
if (PP_display = 1)
    xHigh  = security(ticker,"D", high[0])
    xLow   = security(ticker,"D", low[0])
    xClose = security(ticker,"D", close[0])
    vPP = (xHigh+xLow+xClose) / 3
    vR1 = vPP+(vPP-xLow)
    vS1 = vPP-(xHigh - vPP)
    vR2 = vPP + (xHigh - xLow)
    vS2 = vPP - (xHigh - xLow)
    vR3 = xHigh + 2 * (vPP - xLow) 
    vS3 = xLow - 2 * (xHigh - vPP)
    plot(vPP, color=change(vPP) ? na : black, title="vPP", style = linebr, linewidth = width, transp=0)
end if
```

As a result, I'm getting this error : "syntax error at input 'PP_display'".

I can't find why...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to compare `PP_display` variable with an integer you should use `==` *(equal to)* operator. Single `=` is used to declare variables.
2. There is no `end if` in pinescript syntax.
3. You can't use `plot` function in the local scope, only in global.
4. Declaring a variable using the security() function in the local scope will produce a compilation error - `Can't call 'security' inside: 'if', 'for'`

The solution is to move all your calcs, security calls and plot function to the global scope.

If your intention is to hide the plot with the `PP_display` input you could use a ternary conditional operator `? :` directly in the series argument of the `plot` function.

```
//@version=3
study(title="v5.0", shorttitle="v5.0", overlay=true)
PP_display = input(1, minval=0, maxval=1)

xHigh  = security(ticker,"D", high[0])
xLow   = security(ticker,"D", low[0])
xClose = security(ticker,"D", close[0])
vPP = (xHigh+xLow+xClose) / 3
vR1 = vPP+(vPP-xLow)
vS1 = vPP-(xHigh - vPP)
vR2 = vPP + (xHigh - xLow)
vS2 = vPP - (xHigh - xLow)
vR3 = xHigh + 2 * (vPP - xLow) 
vS3 = xLow - 2 * (xHigh - vPP)
    
plot(PP_display == 1 ? vPP : na, color=change(vPP) ? na : black, title="vPP", style = linebr, linewidth = 2, transp=0)
```